# PCRE pattern match verification between 2 files containing multi line regex and data patterns in linux

Tags: regex, linux, perl, pcre

I am new to PCRE pattern matching. Would like to know, that if
I have a file containing different regex patterns, say file1 containing long list of multiline patterns.
Another file, say file2 containing some lines of patterns from file1 (pattern data file).

1. How to verify/find out how many PCRE pattern matches between patterns in file2 and patterns in file1.
2. Was working with pcretest and pcregrep which accepts only 1 pattern file as source or input.
   Wondering is there anyway using pcretest or pcregrep tools or any other pcre tool which accepts 2 files to test the pcre pattern matches between them (here file2 over file1) ?

Or is there anyway/syntax to pass both, different multiline regex patterns and multiline data patterns in a single file to get the pcre matches between those 2 pattern files?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note: Perl doesn't use PCRE

Comment: What seems to be the problem? What code do you have so far?

Comment: Hi Ikegami, I am looking for a tool/procedure based on PCRE which can verify my pattern match between the 2 files as mentioned above, adhering to PCRE. Basically I have another application which claims to find out the PCRE pattern matches from line file2 upon multi line file1. I need a standard or established PCRE bases tool or command or procedure to verify this claim.

Comment: I was thinking something like pcretest [option flags] content of file2 which pcre matches content of file1, but sending 2 files as argument is not possible for pcretest.

Comment: Say for example file1 may contain patterns like abcd 23d2e eciuh abcdefgh 2398eabcd#(&  and file 2 contains abcd 23. Then output should show how many and which patterns from file2 PCRE matches with that in file1. Atleast how many PCRE matches.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. I'm asking what problem are you having writing the program.

Comment: May be my query is not clear, I am not looking for code. To simplify my query, I am looking how to pass multiline pattern data (in file2) along with the multiline regex patterns (in file1) in pcretest or pcregrep (or any other pcre tool) so as to get the pcre matches.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for readers patience, seems I have found the solution from some other site.
This looks very basic, but this is my first time experience with patterns.

Say **file1** contains the regex patterns to be tested,
and **file2** contains the lines of text patterns to test.

Since pcretest can have only 1 file as input, the syntax will be thus,
append both these files (file1 & file2) in a file (say **testfile**) such that,
Each regex pattern is on the first line, and must be enclosed in delimiters
The text patterns to be tested in the next line onwards.

If multi lines, then below each delimited regex pattern line, keep all the data pattern lines.

Skip a line and again below second delimited regex pattern line keep all the data pattern lines.

**e.g.,**

**file1** contains regex patterns

```
Bharat\d{4}   
bharata(\w+)\b
```

**file2** contains data patterns

```
bsgdfr 242  
23egjuy Bharati ytf  
uhouho Bharat567 uhgf  
poiuhgpoij   
ygf bkutgl 657  
ytfui bharatauwa65 rtesrydu
```

Then **testfile** should be created to contain,

```
/Bharat\d{4}/  
bsgdfr 242  
23egjuy Bharati ytf  
uhouho Bharat567 uhgf  
poiuhgpoij   
ygf bkutgl 657  
ytfui bharatauwa65 rtesrydu  

/\bharata(\w+)\b/  
bsgdfr 242  
23egjuy Bharati ytf  
uhouho Bharat567 uhgf  
poiuhgpoij   
ygf bkutgl 657  
ytfui bharatauwa65 rtesrydu
```

**Now run**

```
pcretest [option flags] testfile resultfile
```

result file has the matches.

One can add as many regex pattern lines and lines of data patterns as required.

Comment: Unable to put the example it in correct viewable format in stackoverflow. The format is described

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for help on formatting your posts.